# Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<Service> into App.kt using Dagger2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, onesignal

i try to use dependency injection also in the service that handles recive notification.

I followed the solution by Nauce https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/253

**App.kt**

```
class App : MultiDexApplication(), HasServiceInjector {

    @Inject lateinit var dispatchingServiceInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Service>

    companion object {
        lateinit var applicationComponent: ApplicationComponent
    }

    override fun serviceInjector() = dispatchingServiceInjector

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent
                .builder()
                .applicationModule(ApplicationModule(this))
                .build()
    }
}
```

**MyOneSignalMessagingService.kt**

```
@Singleton
class MyOneSignalMessagingService : NotificationExtenderService() {

    @Inject lateinit var ApiService: ApiService

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    }

  override fun onNotificationProcessing(notification: OSNotificationReceivedResult?): Boolean {
      // He i want to use ApiService
}
```

But I cannot inject `dispatchingServiceInjector` in **App.kt**.

It will throw `lateinit property dispatchingServiceInjector has not been initialized`, when`MyOneSignalMessagingService` receive the notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't injecting your Application. Note in [Nauce's example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/253#issuecomment-352210847) that ApplicationComponent has this method:

```
@Component(/* ... */) @Singleton public interface AppComponent {
  /* ... */
  void inject(App app);
}
```

By making a one-arg method that returns `void`, you've defined a [members-injection method](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.16/dagger/Component.html#members-injection-methods), which populates `@Inject`-annotated fields and calls `@Inject`-annotated methods on an existing object instance. Because Android itself creates your Application instance, it will not have its `@Inject` fields populated automatically, so it's up to you to inject it with your component. (You do the same in Services and Activities by calling `AndroidInjection.inject(this)`, but because you're responsible for creating your own Component implementation, there's no equivalent call for Application.)

Without defining AppInjector, Nauce calls this in `onCreate`:

```
AppInjector.init(this);
```

But in your example, this would look more like this, in App.kt:

```
override fun onCreate() {
  super.onCreate()

  applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent
      .builder()
      .applicationModule(ApplicationModule(this))
      .build()

  // Inject this class's @Inject-annotated members.
  applicationComponent.inject(this)
}
```

For future reference, you also have the choice to extend from [DaggerApplication](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.16/dagger/android/DaggerApplication.html) (in dagger.android or dagger.android.support), which would automatically provide all of your injectors as long as you make your ApplicationComponent extend `AndroidInjector<App>` and return it from the [`applicationInjector()` method](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.16/dagger/android/DaggerApplication.html#applicationInjector--).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!